# VS Code 1.86 update changed Go syntax highlighting. Why?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I found that the code color sent changed before and after the update, I used the one dark pro plugin
before：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhHfx.png)
after:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nkgpp.png)
Wonder why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VS Code's Go textmate grammar was updated in 1.86. See [this maintainer comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/203998#issuecomment-1923734914). Quoting from [the updated release notes](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/pull/7012/files):

> The Go syntax highlighting grammar has been changed to use [Go Syntax](https://github.com/worlpaker/go-syntax), which is more actively maintained than the previous grammar.